# Python: Can't Filter CSV, ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV like this:

```
| path                            | artists | item | id                 |  
| ------------------------------- | ------- | ---- | ------------------ |
| ../gifs/dwight\_harry\_0.gif    | dh      | 0    | wUIh5rHf5QCyhIk8Ay |
| ../gifs/dwight\_beatles\_0.gif  | db      | 0    | OqBPFGQkA2rmoouv4A |
| ../gifs/michael\_harry\_0.gif   | mh      | 0    | ITAra7ShPMXQecbFGZ |
| ../gifs/michael\_beatles\_0.gif | mb      | 0    | ryKfGjpxOvDM38b3sk |
| ../gifs/michael\_beatles\_0.gif | mb      | 1    | hgKfGjpxOdfM38b3sk |
```

I want to first filter it by item and then select each `artists` value one  by one. For example, for `item = 1`, I would select only `mb`.
This is what I've tried:

```py
item = 0 
i = str(item)

df = pd.read_csv("../data/urls.csv")
# Select Item
df = df.loc[df['item'] == i]
    
dh_id = df.loc[df['artists'] == 'dh']['id'].item()
db_id = df.loc[df['artists'] == 'db']['id'].item()
mh_id = df.loc[df['artists'] == 'mh']['id'].item()
mb_id = df.loc[df['artists'] == 'mb']['id'].item()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  File "D:\write_pages.py", line 67, in writepage
    dh_id = df.loc[df['artists'] == 'dh']['id'].item()

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi!! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

try:

```
df=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.strip(),axis=1)
out=df.groupby('artists')['id'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().idxmax())
```

output of `out`:

```
artists
db    OqBPFGQkA2rmoouv4A
dh    wUIh5rHf5QCyhIk8Ay
mb    hgKfGjpxOdfM38b3sk
mh    ITAra7ShPMXQecbFGZ
Name: id, dtype: object
```

**OR**

drop duplicated values of 'artists':

```
out=df.sort_values('item',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('artists')
```

output of out:

```
     path                               artists     item    id
0   ../gifs/michael\_beatles\_0.gif     mb          1       hgKfGjpxOdfM38b3sk
1   ../gifs/dwight\_harry\_0.gif        dh          0       wUIh5rHf5QCyhIk8Ay
2   ../gifs/dwight\_beatles\_0.gif      db          0       OqBPFGQkA2rmoouv4A
3   ../gifs/michael\_harry\_0.gif       mh          0       ITAra7ShPMXQecbFGZ
```

**Note:** you are getting this error because `df.loc[df['artists'] == 'mb']['id']` giving you 2 values and according to the documentation of [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html) It will raise value error If the data is not length-1 and the value need to be scaler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How is it giving me two values though? First, I'm trying to filter by saying only look at rows where `item = 1` (for example) and then select the `id` of `mb`. Wouldn't that always be a singular value, because `item` is unique? Additionally, in the code you've provided, where is the value of `item` being input? Is it `axis = 1`?

Comment: @Aman bcz you didn't apply any filter that will select only id of mb where `item==1(unique)`

Comment: @Aman updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**